# Nginx Windows URL Rewrite Error

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I installed a portable nginx and php5.3 on windows 7 64bit and I created a sample site needs a url rewrite to run this is the error I always get after my configuration.

```
2014/11/30 22:56:12 [crit] 2356#3384: *1 GetFileAttributesEx() "D:/nginx/nginx/nginx-1.2.3/html/main.site.dev/index.php/" failed (123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect), client: 192.168.1.109, server: main.site.web, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "main.site.web"
```

here is my current windows nginx server block config:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  main.site.web;
        root D:/nginx/nginx/nginx-1.2.3/html/main.site.dev;
        location / {
            try_files $uri index.php$uri$args /index.php$uri$args /index.php;
        }      

        location ~ \.php\/(.+)$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            break;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location = /php-fpm-ping {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            include     fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Notice the "/" at the end of "index.php". What is wrong with the configuration.
Also note that the directory on this window is fully controlled (read & write).

Any suggestion or comments are appreciated. Thank you in advance...

Comment: define `index` and change `.+` to `.*` in regexps in the 2nd location...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have change it with what you told I change  `.+` to `.*` but it still I got error. Do you think the way I type the path of the document root is wrong. I know how to fix this in linux and I am not sure what to type in windows..

Comment: I have tried `root htm/main.site.web;` and it's error, I notice there is a / on index.php like this `GetFileAttributesEx() "d:/nginx/nginx/nginx-1.2.3/html/main.site.dev/index.php/"`

Comment: Check it without `try_files`. I think `try_files` makes this error.

Comment: I had this configuration running on centos 6 same configuration except the document since in centos I use `root /usr/share/nginx/main.site.dev`. I had enough of this. It's really hard to configure nginx on windows machine. I will go back to centos again. Thank you for your time Deadooshka. I really appreciate it.